# Let $I_1$, $I_2$ are fractional ideals, if $a$, $b$ are non-zero elements with $aI_1 \subset R$ and $b \in I_2$ then $ab \in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

First, $R$ is a integral domain, and $K$ is a field of fractions of $R$

Let $I_1$, $I_2$ are fractional ideals, and

$J = \{ x \in K \ | \ x I_2 \subset I_1 \}$

if $a$, $b$ are non-zero elements with $aI_1 \subset R$ and $b \in I_2$ then $abJ \subset R$. So $J$ is a fractional ideal.

It means $ab$ is a element of $R$, and I know $a$ is in $R$ by difinition. Despite $b$ is a element of $I_2$, not $I_2 \cap R$, why $ab$ is a element of $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Let $a=1$, choose $b\in K-R$, and take $I_1=R$ and $I_2=bR$. Then $aI_1\subseteq R$ (in fact $aI_1=R$) but $ab=b\notin R$.

It is true in general by the definition of the fractional ideal $J$ that, under the stated conditions, $abJ\subseteq R$. But $ab$ may not be an element of $J$ (note that $1\in J$ if and only if $I_2\subseteq I_1$).